# Can I store relational database structure in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am a java programmer and I want to use MongoDB in my project. I know that MongoDB is a document database but is there any way to store more fields for a record in this db ?

For example I have a table with 4 attributes (i.e. columns) name address age and dob so can I use or convert this structure to fit into MongoDB ?

Comment: **Moderator Note** _The comments under this question have been removed because the conversation degenerated into far more noise than signal. Please keep comments polite, constructive and on topic._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course.

MongoDB is a document-based database management system.  If you are familiar with the `JSON` format, Mongo stores data in a very similar manner.  For example, a sample document in a Mongo database may look like this:

```
Person {
    Name:
    {
       First : "John"
       Last : "Smith"
    }
    Address :
    {
       City : "Chicago"
       State : "Illinois"
       Street : "30 S. Michigan Avenue"
    }
}
```

As you can see Mongo supports nested fields, so a particular field can contain one or more attributes.  It is not key/value per se, as it is possible to nest document ad infinitum.  Beware, however, that not all documents in a collection have to have the same structure.  This is Mongo's biggest strength, but it can turn around and bite you if you're not careful.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Do you know any other alternative to MongoDB which is not forcing AGPL.

Comment: Only the MongoDB database server itself is licensed under AGPL -- thus if you make any changes to the MongoDB database code, you would be required to commit those changes back to the main codebase. All of the official drivers (including the [Java driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)) are licensed under the Apache License 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the correct (+1) answers from the previous two posters...

There's a difference between "relational database structure" and storing additional attributes. Relational implies that you're modeling relationships between things in your database, like customers and the orders that each customer has.

MongoDB allows you to store documents with many attributes.  It does not provide much support to mange relationships between documents.

Comment: MongoDB allows you to use [Database References](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References) which the official drivers (and many community supplied drivers) know how to interpret to look up the referenced document. However, the database itself does not process DBRefs (i.e. no JOINing).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, MongoDB is not a traditional key/value database but a document database. A document is a JSON object, which can contain any number of fields, or even nested documents. So yes, you can easily store multiple fields for each record.